# Does using separate function for every modules increases the time-complexity & space of that program

Tags: algorithm

Algorithm-Time complexity & Space Complexity. Writing  code in just one main() without using separate function().(**competitive programming**).Does it makes any changes regarding complexities.

Comment: Please edit to improve the grammar of the question to make it more comprehensible

Answer (score 1):

Breaking your program into functions does not change the asymptotic complexity.

However, it can affect the running time. On one hand, it takes time to build stack frames and make function calls. That overhead is typically small compared to the rest of what your program does and compilers these days can inline functions, which will eliminate that overhead.

Functions can also *improve* the speed of your code. Consider, for example, code such as:

```
main()
{
    // do some stuff here
    while (some_condition)
    {
        if (some_other_condition)
        {
            // do a whole bunch of stuff here
        }
        else
        {
            // do some other stuff here
        }
    }
```

It's quite possible that code which calls functions, like this:

```
    while (some_condition)
    {
        if (some_other_condition)
        {
            some_other_condition_true();
        }
        else
        {
            some_other_condition_false();
        }
    }
```

Will execute faster.

*In general*, the few small gains you get, if any, by packing all of your code into a single `main()` function are more than offset by the costs: code that's hard to write, understand, debug, and modify.

Write your code so that it's easy to understand. Use functions and all those other good programming things you've learned. They exist for a reason. Once your program works, then decide if you really need to obfuscate. Usually, a better algorithm is going to outperform any other type of "optimization" you might make. A good algorithm can make orders of magnitude difference in your running time. Optimization tricks typically save you a few percentage points of running time.

Answer (score 1):

No.

When we talk about time complexity and space complexity, we always ignore constant factors; for example, a function *f* is O(*n*) if there exists some constant *k*, no matter how large, such that *f*(*n*) ≤ *kn* for all sufficiently large *n*.

The overhead of calling a separate function to do something, as opposed to doing that thing inline, is a constant — it doesn't depend on the size of your input — so it doesn't affect the algorithmic complexity.

(There are some exceptions to this if the function-calling convention involves copying a large object that *does* depend on the size of your input — for example, in C++, if you pass a `std::vector<int>` by value, then that copies the full contents of the vector — but such cases are always easily addressed, e.g. by passing it by reference. So it's not the function call itself that's the problem, it's additional implicit overhead that you might accidentally cause. Copying a `std::vector<int>` is just as expensive whether or not you're calling a function, it's just that you're more likely to accidentally copy a `std::vector<int>` if you're calling a function than if you're writing inline.)